# Can't call alert from Server Side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, clientscript

In Web Forms project i need to open alert.

I try to do it like this

```
var script = Page.ClientScript;
                            if (!script.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "SignOffAlert"))
                            {
                                script.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "text", "SignOffAlert");
                            }
```

and add js-function on view

```
function SignOffAlert() {
            alert('The form cannot be submitted!');
        }
```

On Button click alert is absent

---

Update :

This code works for me

```
var script = Page.ClientScript;
                            if (!script.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "signOffAlert"))
                            {
                                script.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "signOffAlert", "alert('The form cannot be submitted!');", true);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,
in the Page_Load write this:

```
string myscript = "  <script> function SignOffAlert() { alert('The form cannot be submitted!');}</script>";

    if (! Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "SignOffAlert"))
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "text", myscript);
    }
```

and in then Form

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="SignOffAlert()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the full script, i believe

have you seen the example here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bahh2fef%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: if something like this `script.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "text", "SignOffAlert()");` than also don't want to work

Comment: em, wait a moment, i get exception before i render my alert

Comment: i updaated the answer